# Combobox using Sencha Architect

Tags: elasticsearch, extjs, sencha-architect

I been trying to load datas from elasticsearch into combobox but unsuccessfully, however load datas from json file to combobox it work.

the only different that is that load data from the store on json file, it successfully loaded the data, but when for elasticsearch, it reply '400: Bad Request'

[Json File]

```
    [
 {
"index":"color",
"_type":"_doc",
"_id":1,
"_score":1.0,
"_source": 
  {
    "name":"Red"
  }
 },
 {
"index":"color",
"_type":"_doc",
"_id":2,
"_score":1.0,
"_source": 
  {
    "name":"Blue"
  }
 }
]
```

[ElasticSearch Json Reply]

```
  {
  "took":3,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":
  {
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "skipped":0,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
    "total":{
      "value":4,
      "relation":"eq"
    },
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index":"color",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":1,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Red"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"color",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":2,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Blue"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"color",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":3,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Green"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"color",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":4,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Yellow"
        }
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

My Model Code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ColorModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.colormodel,

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.String',
        'Ext.data.field.Integer'
    ],

    fields: [
      {
        type:'string',
        name:'_index'
      },
      {
        type:'string',
        name:'_type'
      },
      {
        type:'string',
        name:'_id'
      },
      {
        type:'int',
        name:'_score'
      },
      {
        name:'_source'
      },
    ]

});
```

My Store Code [Json File- That Work]

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.ColorStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store",
    
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.ColorModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cgf || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId:'ColorStore',
            model:'MyApp.model.ColorModel',
            proxy: {
                type:'ajax',
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/data/color.json,
                withCredentials:true,
                reader: {
                    type:'json' 
                }
              }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

[My Another Store that retrieve from elasticsearch] - not working

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.ESColorStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store",
    
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.ColorModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cgf || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId:'ESColorStore',
            model:'MyApp.model.ColorModel',
            proxy: me.processMyAjaxProxy1({
                type:'ajax',
                read: function(operation, callback, scope){
                    var request = this.bulidRequest(operation, callback,scope);
                    var query = {
                        "from": operation.params.from,
                        "size": operation.params.size,
                        "query": {
                            "query_string" : { }
                        },
                        "sort": [
                        {
                           "name.raw":{
                            "order": "asc"
                            }
                        }   
                        ]
                    };


                Ext.apply(request, {
                    headers: this.headers,
                    timeout: this.timeout,
                    scope: this,
                    callback: this.createRequestCallback(request,operation,callback,scope),
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: operation.params,
                    jsonData: query,
                    disableCaching:true,
                    success: function(rec) {
                        console.log('[ESColorStore], successfully retrieved query: ' + rec.responseText);
                    }
                    failure: function(rec) {
                        console.log('[ESColorStore], failed retrieved query: ' + rec.responseText);
                    }
                });

                Ext.Ajax.request(request);
                
                return request;
                },
                reader: {
                    type:'json' 
                }
              }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    proccessMyAjaxProxy1: function(config) {
        config.api = {
            read: 'http://localhost:9200/color/_search'
        };
        config.url = 'http://localhost:9200/color/';
        return config
    },
});
```

[Views]

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.MyPanelViewModel',
        'Ext.field.ComboBox'
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'mypanel'
    },
    title: 'My Panel',
    
    items: [
      {
        xtype:'comobobox',
        name:'select-the-color',
        width: 419,
        docked: 'top',
        label:'Select The Color',
        autoLoadOnValue: true,
        displayField: '_source.name',
        selectOnTab:false,
        store:'ESColorStore',
        valueField:'_source.name',
        queryCaching: false,
        queryParam:''
      }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Can you add the configurations for combobox and its store, or just provide a fiddle where a hardcoded elastic data is not getting loaded.

Comment: @wahabmemon, i update the configurations

Comment: In your ESColoreStore, why are you using POST. You are trying to GET the elastic data right? So the method name should be GET

Comment: i try to change from POST to GET but still the same it keep "[ESColorStore], failed retrieved query" without any responseText